# Chrome tab search no longer works on some sites

Tags: google-chrome, browser, search, autocomplete, omnibox

I've used Chrome for years.  One of my favorite features is that once you've been to a site with a search, you can later type the site name and hit tab to search from the omnibox. For instance on Youtube:

[image]

A few months ago this stopped working for google images.  Typing "images" and hitting tab results in it just going to the next item in the autocomplete.

A couple days ago this stopped working for Amazon.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out there is an interface to manage these in "Manage Search Engines".  Oddly, images.google.com was still there and without making any changes (I just clicked the field to view the full value) it started working again.

Amazon was gone, so I readded it: `https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=%s`

I then had to fiddle with it a couple times but now it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Is Google still your default search engine?...  or did some page/extension/program change it on you?...  perhaps check here:

```
Set your default search engine
On your computer, open Chrome.
At the top right, click [3 bars/dots button] and then Settings.
In the "Search" section, next to your current default search engine, click the Down arrow Down Arrow.
Select a new default search engine.
```

Comment: Google is/was still my default search engine. This was not related.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that google no longer uses the domain "images.google.com" once you actually hit search it reverts to a google.com domain with unintelligible results. As @the-joatmon mentioned, the problem can be sovled within the setting "Manage Search Engines"

Add the following:

- Shortcut: [www.images.google.com](http://www.images.google.com)
- URL: `https://www.google.com/search?q=%s&hl=en&sxsrf=ALiCzsaUq-AMIX87U4GFasVx8Sqiqtu9aw:1659457287223&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJv_-QyKj5AhWqQjABHXDpBIsQ_AUoAXoECAMQAw`

Note that one downside here is you actually need to type `www.images.google.com` rather than the shorthand `images.google.com`